# How to manually getValue when using magicSuggest plugin?

Tags: jquery, methods, magicsuggest

using MagicSuggest plugin:
http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html

I'm trying to manually get the selected values of a magicSuggest object. There's no documentation on how to getValue() manually/on demand.. all the examples show how to getValue() when selectionchange() event is invoked.

So I tried to do a getValue on the object itself and it gives me a getValue is not a function Error.

here's the code:

```
//TYPE AHEAD
ms_search = $("#search-field").magicSuggest({
    data: '?act=search_employees',
    valueField: 'eid',
    displayField: 'fname',

    maxSelection: 1
});

$(ms_search).on('selectionchange', function(e,m){
    alert("values: " + JSON.stringify(this.getValue()));
});
```

everything works so far... but when i try to run

```
console.log( $(ms_search).getValue()) ;
```

i get an error:  "getValue is not a function"

Comment: Have you tried `ms_search.getValue()` e.g. not making it a jQuery object ?

Comment: yup that one worked. got confused. tnx

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the examples all use a getValue() on the selectionChange because of convenience. It allows to have multiple examples on the same page and only triggering events on what is needed.

To answer your question, `ms_search.getValue()` will work as long as ms_search is still defined.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sWyr/3/

(disclaimer: i made the plugin)

Comment: hmm.. makes sense.. alright thanks man, and thanks for the plugin..still getting used to it but it's fab so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` to select the selected item. This is dummy workaround:

```
jQuery(".yourdivfield .ms-sel-ctn .ms-sel-item").length > 0
```